# Draining wiper fluid

Tags: ford, fiesta

I've not been able to find a similar question on this topic, so apologies if it is a duplicate.

I picked up a new car at the beginning of the week and noticed that after using the wiper fluid it leaves behind a 'stain' of sorts and it is marking the paintwork.

I have no clue as to what mixture/concoction of fluid is currently being used, so I have decided it would be best to drain, flush and replace with something I know.

Is there a 'standard' way to drain wiper fluid?

***Note: I have 0 mechanical experience and the car in question is a 2011 Ford Fiesta.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two ways there:

1. Just drain it empty
2. Overfill your wiper fluid container with water. That way you could
   wash the old fluid out or at least thin it. Then drain empty again.

Because to unscrew the wiper fluid container is not so easy without mechanical experience and even danger, I would not do that on your place.

Comment: I'll just continue to use the existing supply and ensure I wipe off any left over residue - seems the most hassle free method :)

Answer (score 0):

get your hands on a thin hose or other bendy pipe, stick it in there and start sucking til the fluid comes out. Keep the end you sucked on lower than the bottle and let physics do the hard work for you.

It's best to use a see-through pipe so you can tell when you're about to get a mouthful of soap.

When you refill, it would be a good idea to use methylated spirits or cleaning alcohol diluted (very much) in water. As a bonus it gives off a nice smell in the cabin.